# Variable value substitution in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, cron, sh, variable-assignment

Suppose in a Linux shell script, I have `WHATIF_POLLING_SCHEDULER="0 * * ? * *"`.
Now I do: `ESCAPED_WHATIF_POLLING_SCHEDULER=\"${WHATIF_POLLING_SCHEDULER}\"`

```
CRON1="-Dwhatif.polling.scheduler=$ESCAPED_WHATIF_POLLING_SCHEDULER"
```

Finally, I have to do `java -jar $MY_JAR` and pass this cron paramater in it.
So, when I do `java "$CRON1" -jar $MY_JAR` I am getting error like 'invalid value in cron parser'

While if I simply substitute the value `java -Dwhatif.polling.scheduler="0 * * ? * *" -jar $MY_JAR` it works fine.
I need to pass the CRON1 variable correctly in Java command.

Comment: It's not clear what you pretend.  Is it possible that you rephrase yourself to clarify?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `ESCAPED_WHATIF_POLLING_SCHEDULER=\"${WHATIF_POLLING_SCHEDULER}\"`.

Note that `java -Dwhatif.polling.scheduler="0 * * ? * *" -jar "$MY_JAR"` does not really contain quotes in the value of the parameter. The quotes are part of the shell syntax.

The following commands are 100% identical from the viewpoint of the shell:

- `java "-Dwhatif.polling.scheduler=0 * * ? * *" -jar "$MY_JAR"`
- `java -D"whatif.polling.scheduler"="0 * * ? * *" -jar "$MY_JAR"`
- `java -D"whatif.polling.scheduler=0 * * ? * *" -jar "$MY_JAR"`
- `java -Dwhatif.polling.scheduler=0" ""*"" ""*"" ""?"" ""*"" "*" -jar "$MY_JAR"`
- `java -Dwhatif.polling.scheduler=0\ \*\ \*\ \?\ \*\ \* -jar "$MY_JAR"`
- `java -Dwhatif.polling.scheduler='0 * * ? * *' -jar "$MY_JAR"`
- `java -Dwhatif.polling."scheduler=0 * * ? * *" -jar "$MY_JAR"`

So the command that you executed is equivalent to:

```
java -Dwhatif.polling.scheduler='"0 * * ? * *"' -jar "$MY_JAR"
```

You actually want to run:

```
WHATIF_POLLING_SCHEDULER='0 * * ? * *'
java -Dwhatif.polling.scheduler="$WHATIF_POLLING_SCHEDULER" -jar "$MY_JAR"
```

or maybe:

```
WHATIF_POLLING_SCHEDULER='0 * * ? * *'
CRON1="-Dwhatif.polling.scheduler=$WHATIF_POLLING_SCHEDULER"
java "$CRON1" -jar "$MY_JAR"
```

There's no need to embed quotes in your value, because the quotes are not actually part of the value.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `CRON1` contains the string `-Dwhatif.polling.scheduler="0 * * ? * *"` and this is what Java gets as first parameter, while when you type the version of your code which works fine, Java sees as first parameter the string `-Dwhatif.polling.scheduler=0 * * ? * *`.

I guess that Java is simply upset by the double quotes in your parameter. You are adding them when calculating `ESCAPED_WHATIF_POLLING_SCHEDULER`, so you should have done instead

```
 CRON1="-Dwhatif.polling.scheduler=$WHATIF_POLLING_SCHEDULER"
```

or alternatively remove the double quotes from the content of your `CRON1` variable (i.e. pass

```
"${CRON1//'"'//}"
```

to java)